How to retrieve the Pinia Store State variable globally in Vue3?
I'm trying to access the Pinia Store State variable from another component (coming from my Websocket Server). Inisde the Store, the message comes up correctly. However, when I try to reference the object from another component, it doesn't.
Here's my code from my useWebSocketStore.js:
import { useWebSocketStore } from '../../stores/useWebSocketStore.js';
import _ from "lodash";

export function createRoutes() {
    return [
        { path: '/home', component: Home, meta: { title: 'Home' } },
        { path: '/feed', component: Feed, meta: { title: 'Feed' } },
        { path: '/chatrooms', component: ChatRooms, meta: { title: 'ChatRooms' } },
        {
            path: '/chatrooms/:chatroomNameField',
            component: ChatroomTemplate,
            props: true,
            name: 'toChatroom',
            beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
                try {
                    const webSocketStore = useWebSocketStore();

                    // Ensure the WebSocket is connected (connect if not already connected)
                    if (!webSocketStore.isConnected) {
                        await webSocketStore.connect();
                    }

                    const getChatroomName = _.get(to.params, 'chatroomNameField', '');
                    const msg = {
                        wsAction: "FindChatroom",
                        chatroomName: getChatroomName,
                    }
                    const jsonMsg = JSON.stringify(msg);
                    //webSocketStore.emitMessage("message", jsonMsg);

                    try {
                        webSocketStore.emitMessage("message", jsonMsg);
                        const response = webSocketStore.findChatroomBool;
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error finding chatroom:', error);
                    }

                    //const response = await webSocketStore.socket.on('FindChatroom');
                    //const response = webSocketStore.handleFindChatroom();
                    //alert(response);

                } catch (error) {
                    next('/chatrooms');
                }
            }
        },
        { path: '/games', component: Games, meta: { title: 'Games' } },
        { path: '/create-account', component: CreateAccount, meta: { title: 'Create Account' } },
        { path: '/recover-account', component: AccountRecovery, meta: { title: 'Recover Account' } },
        { path: '/:catchAll(.*)', component: NotFound, meta: { title: 'Not Found' } },
        { path: '/', redirect: '/home' }
    ];
}

And here is where I'm trying to retrieve it (in another component):
// stores/useWebSocketStore.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import {useRouter} from "vue-router";

export const useWebSocketStore = defineStore('webSocket', {
    state: () => ({
        socket: null,
        isConnected: ref(false),
        findChatroomBool: ref(''),
    }),
    actions: {
        connect() {
            if (!this.socket || this.socket.disconnected) {
                this.socket = io('https://blah.com:3000', {
                    secure: true,
                    transports: ['websocket'],
                });

                this.socket.on('connect', () => {
                    this.isConnected = true;
                    console.log('Connected to WebSocket server');

                    // Add event listener for 'chatroomNameExists' after connection is established
                    this.socket.on('chatroomNameExists', () => {
                        alert('Chatroom name already exists. Use another one.');
                        const router = useRouter();
                        router.push('/chatrooms').catch(err => {
                            console.error("Navigation error:', err");
                        })
                    })
                });

                this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                    this.isConnected = false;
                    console.log('Disconnected from WebSocket server');
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.connect(); // Attempt to reconnect
                    }, 3000); // Reconnect after 3 seconds
                });

                this.socket.on('message', (message) => {
                    console.log('Received message:', message);
                });

                this.socket.on('error', (error) => {
                    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
                });

                this.socket.on('alert', (alertMsg) => {
                    alert(alertMsg);
                });

                this.socket.on('FindChatroom', (msg) => {
                    this.socket.findChatroomBool = msg;
                });
            }
        },
        emitMessage(event, message) {
            try {
                this.socket.emit(event, message);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("Error emitting message", e.stack);
            }
            /*if (!this.socket.isConnected) {
                this.socket.connect();
            }
            this.socket.emit(event, message);

            if (this.socket && this.socket.connected) {
                this.socket.emit(event, message);
            } else {
                console.error('WebSocket is not connected');
            }*/
        },

Is my set up wrong? I keep getting undefined as a response.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. It's not obvious that this.socket.findChatroomBool is the same as webSocketStore.findChatroomBool. And even if it is, this means that you set findChatroomBool to undefined at some point, probably with = msg, because it's initially empty string

this.socket.findChatroomBool = msg; looks wrong - why are you adding findChatroomBool property to this.socket?

@JaromandaX I'm having the database look through a Chatroom database. If a user tries to create a chatroom with the same name, and the database finds a chatroom with the same name, it returns true to the Client. It's working on the Stores component, but when I'm trying to pass it to another component in my Vue3 project, it comes up as undefined.

@EstusFlask I updated my code. Maybe that'll help.

but why are you this.socket.findChatroomBool = msg; ... when findChatroomBool  is NOT a property of your state

@JaromandaX Only way I could think of. Is there a better way to store this variable so other components can access it?

so, what is the purpose of findChatroomBool in state - since you never use it?

@JaromandaX I'm trying to use it in my first script under the try-catch statement. It's supposed to return a variable of "true" or "false" depending on if the chatroom exists on my database. It returns correctly inside the Pinia store, but it doesn't return correctly inside the "router" in the first script.
I've already tried printing it out in the console, and it gives me undefined. I was going to use it to route the user to the chatroom if the chatroom did exist, or route them back to the main page if it didn't.

but const response = webSocketStore.findChatroomBool; retrieves state.findChatroomBool from the pinia store ... and this.socket.findChatroomBool = msg; has nothing to do with that. In fact, the code you posted only ever sets this.socket.findChatroomBool and only ever gets findChatroomBool from pinia state ... the two properties are in no way linked. What happens if you, for example, replace this.socket.findChatroomBool = msg; with this.findChatroomBool = msg;
